# React native two way binding with another component

Tags: react-native

I just learning react native for three weeks and i have difficulty to update custom controller value based on the state in the parent.

Here is the fiddle:[js fiddle to react native](https://www.rnplay.org/apps/_P-TXA)

In the code, when i type from custom control input, the parent input got updated. But when i type from the parent input, the custom control input is not updated.

Can you point out my mistakes please?

Also here is my code:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput
} = React;

var CustomControl = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onChangeTextValue: React.PropTypes.func,
        value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            onChangeTextValue: () => { },
            value: ""
        }
    },

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        text: this.props.value
    };
},

setText: function(value) {
    this.setState({
        text: value
    });
    try {
        return this.props.onChangeTextValue(value);
    } catch (_error) { }
},

render: function(){
    return (
        <TextInput
            style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray',
                     borderWidth: 1 }}
            onChangeText={this.setText}
            value={this.state.text}
            />
        )
    }
});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            'textValue': ''
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text>
                  Parent Input
              </Text>
              <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textValue:text})}
        value={this.state.textValue}
              />
              <Text>
                  Custom control input
              </Text>

              <CustomControl
        onChangeTextValue={(text) => this.setState({textValue:text})}
                value={this.state.textValue}
              />

              <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                  Updating the parent input should update the custom control value too. Right now only when we update the custom control value, the parent input is updated.
              </Text>

          </View>
        );
    }
});
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing state in your child component which you shouldn't be, the parent component passes a handler onChangeTextValue which you should be using instead.

Try instead for your child component

```
var CustomControl = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onChangeTextValue: React.PropTypes.func,
        value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <TextInput
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray',
                         borderWidth: 1 }}
                onChangeText={this.props.onChangeTextValue}
                value={this.props.value}
                />
            )
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i need. :)